How can I do TCP hand-off in Node.js?
I am a student studying Node.js.
I'm creating a game server as a project this time, and when the client accesses the authentication session server and the authentication is completed, I want to hand over the socket connected to the authentication session to the game server.
Thank you for reading it.
Previously, authentication and game server were combined into one.
I wanted to introduce the concept of a distributed server this time, so I was looking into it, but it was difficult to find the data in the way I wanted.

A proxy can make it look like they are the same server.

You Can’t Do That™. Connected sockets belong to processes. You’ll need to feed the client some kind of authentication token and have it reconnect to the second server.

Yes, but ... you can actually transfer a socket between processes at least on UNIX systems - see Can I open a socket and pass it to another process in Linux. But, this will only transfer the in-kernel parts (fd, buffers) and not any user space state like SSL, content of user space buffers etc. So while theoretically possible it is usually not a good idea and your recommended approach is prefererred.
